# What is the graph format that I should pass to ArcListASCIIGraph from the Webgraph framework?

Tags: java, graph, compression

I am trying to compress a graph using the WebGraph framework. I have set up the jars I need and I use the following code:

```
ImmutableGraph ig = ArcListASCIIGraph.load(BoldiTest.class.getResource("/citation-csconf-mult5-PaperJSON.graph.txt").getFile());
System.out.println(ig.numNodes()+" "+ig.numArcs());
ImmutableGraph.store(BVGraph.class, ig, "output");
```

The graph is loaded correctly but fails to be stored for the graph I am interested. For a much smaller graph (3 arcs) everything goes well so I guess the code is correct.

I provide the Stack Trace below. Any ideas? (the numbers are nodes and arcs)

```
124538 249755 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at it.unimi.dsi.big.webgraph.ImmutableGraph.store(ImmutableGraph.java:623)
    at it.unimi.dsi.big.webgraph.ImmutableGraph.store(ImmutableGraph.java:638)
    at gr.di.uoa.a8.boldi.BoldiTest.main(BoldiTest.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at it.unimi.dsi.big.webgraph.ImmutableGraph.store(ImmutableGraph.java:619)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at it.unimi.dsi.big.webgraph.BVGraph.updateBins(BVGraph.java:1701)
    at it.unimi.dsi.big.webgraph.BVGraph.storeInternal(BVGraph.java:1808)
    at it.unimi.dsi.big.webgraph.BVGraph.store(BVGraph.java:1650)
    at it.unimi.dsi.big.webgraph.BVGraph.store(BVGraph.java:1678)
    at it.unimi.dsi.big.webgraph.BVGraph.store(BVGraph.java:1690)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After eliminating the duplicate edges and sorting the input file I managed to store the graph.

Comment: Please expand your answer and provide code to make your answer more useful.

Comment: The code posted in the question is correct, the problem was that the input file contained duplicate lines and was not sorted, and that caused the above exception.

`sort -n citation-csconf-mult5-PaperJSON.graph.txt | uniq > newfile.txt`

did the trick